# Getting a total of the (filtered) unique articles in a table visualization in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, distinct, powerbi-desktop, distinct-values

I have this table-visualization in PowerBi formed by using data from diverse tables and with several filters. How do I get a total-row which shows the amount of unique articles in this visualization?

In the screenshot there's a piece of this visualization.

[image]

According to this screenshot the total-row should come up with "10", because of the 10 unique 'artnr'. Preferably it should change as soon as the filters are set differently.

Comment: Where do you want to use the UniqueArticle ? As measure in this table? Propably this should work:

UniqueArticle = calculate( distintcount(Table[artnr]), ALL(Table[artnr]) )

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Could you please explain where to put this code? Should it be entered in the Power Query section somewhere?

Comment: This is a DAX syntax; You should put it in a new measure in your table. Main powerbi-desktop window on the left side, click on the table, and choice "New Measure", then put this measure to your result.

Comment: This is working, though slow. For now I can work with this just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

msta42a gave a right answer. I used it to solve my question.

```
UniqueArticle = calculate(distinctcount(Table[artnr]), ALL(Table[artnr]))
```